# Struggling to prove that the elements of an inverse matrix satisfy a certain equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have three vectors $\vec{e_1},\vec{e_2},\vec{e_3}$ that are not necessarily orthogonal or normalised, but do form a basis.

We also have a matrix $G$ with elements $G_{ij}=\vec{e_i} \ . \vec{e_j}$, and we are told that $H=G^{-1}$.

The question asks to show that the vectors $\vec{f_i}=\sum_jH_{ij}\vec{e_j}$ are the reciprocal vectors of $\vec{e_i}$, which I have done. It then asks to show that $H_{ij}=\vec{f_i}\ .\vec{f_j}$. I've been trying to prove this latter statement for about two hours and I've had no luck whatsoever. How do I go about proving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true. Here is a counter-example.
$$
e_1 = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}, e_2  = \pmatrix{1\\1\\0}, e_3 = \pmatrix{0\\0\\1},
$$
$$
G=\pmatrix{1&1&0\\1&2&0\\0&0&1},
H= \pmatrix{2&-1&0\\-1&1&0\\0&0&1}
$$
$$
f_1=\pmatrix{2\\-1\\0}, f_2 = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}, f_3=e_3,
$$
$$
(f_i\cdot f_j) = \pmatrix{ 5&2&0\\2&1&0\\0&0&1} \ne H
$$

Comment: Interestingly your $f_1$ isn't the reciprocal vector of $e_1$, so something must have been wrong with my first proof also. Thank you :)